# Some menu item in bottom navigation view not showing

Tags: java, android, xml, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottom navigation view with a menu named navi_menu.xml:

```
<item android:id="@+id/navigation_menu_1"
        android:title="Banks"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_a_24"/>


    <item android:id="@+id/navigation_menu_2"
        android:title="Networks"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_b_24"/>
```

The layout file is activity_main:

```
<!--    <constraint layout>-->
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/navi_menu" />
```

This is how it looks like:
[image]

If I remove the background color from activity_main:

```
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
```

This is what I get:
[image]

Even when I switch the placement of the menu items, making `navigation_menu_2` come first the icons were just interchanged the problem still remained.

Please help.

Comment: Did you check the color used for the selected item?

Comment: I figured the color was not the problem because after interchanging the the menu items position ie navigation_menu_2 coming first the same thing happened but the icons were switched